# How can I debug or view logs of live app?

Tags: flutter

I have no idea what to do. My flutter app works flawlessly on test devices and on simulators. No problem.

But when I upload it to the App Store, there's one part that fails.

It works perfectly on test devices and simulators (Android & iOS).

So I want to launch the app on a device (after it has been installed from either the app store, or the play store) and debug it.

How can I do this?

I prefer to use my Android phone to do this.. I have debugging mode turned already. But the question is : how do I connect my Android Studio IDE to view the verbose output from the app. I need to see what is happening...

Thanks

Comment: You should look into [crashlytics by firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics)

Comment: Have you tried to run the app on your phone with `build --release` ?

Comment: Hi Abbas. How do i do that???